# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]:?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I'm trying to build an infinite scroll with search. So far I came to this problem:

> `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC LIMIT 0, 4'.`

Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
if(isset($_GET["starts"], $_GET["limits"])){
 $search = htmlspecialchars($_GET['Search'],ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8');
$start = htmlspecialchars($_GET['starts'],ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
$limit = htmlspecialchars($_GET['limits'],ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  `jobtitle`, `company`, `location`, 
`employment`, `email`, `Description` FROM `featured job` WHERE jobtitle LIKE 
`:jobtitle` DESC LIMIT :starts, :limits");
 $stmt->bindParam(":starts", intval(trim($start)), PDO::PARAM_INT );
 $stmt->bindParam(":limits", intval(trim($limit)), PDO::PARAM_INT );
$stmt->bindParam(":jobtitle",$search);
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($posts as $data) {
  echo "<h2>".$data['jobtitle']."</h2>";
 }
```

Here's my ajax code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var limits = 4;
   var starts = 0;

   var action = 'inactive';
   function load_job_data(limits, starts)
   {
    $.ajax({
   url:"load_more.php",
   method:"GET",
   data:{limits:limits, starts:starts},
   cache:false,
   success:function(data)
   {
   $('.results').append(data);
   if(data == '')
   {
   $('#load_data_messages').text("Your potential jobs is loading");
   $('#load_data_messages').css("color", "green");

   action = 'active';
   }
   else
   {
   $('#load_data_messages').text("Out of jobs! please come back later!");
   $('#load_data_messages').css("color","red");
   action = "inactive";
   }
   }
   });
   }

   if(action == 'inactive')
   {
   action = 'active';
   load_job_data(limits, starts);
   }
   $(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(".load_data").height() 
&& action == 'inactive')
{
 action = 'active';
 starts = starts + limits;
 setTimeout(function(){
 load_job_data(limits, starts);
 }, 1000);
 }
 });

 });
```

Comment: WHERE having a direction doesn't make sense. Are you missing an `ORDER BY` clause? You also shouldn't need the backticks around `:jobtitle`.

Comment: @Jonnix why do I need a order by instead of where

Comment: I expect you want both but I can't tell. It's not an either or, you can have both.

Comment: I feel like you are unsure what the purpose of `htmlspecialchars` is. You should use only when you output something to the HTML. In you case you use on integers which go into the database, and that makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

`:jobtitle`  is not a column name so you  should not use the backtics and you miss the `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT  `jobtitle`
  , `company`
  , `location`
  , `employment`
  , `email`
  , `Description` 
FROM `featured job` 
WHERE jobtitle LIKE :jobtitle 
ORDER BY `jobtitle` DESC LIMIT :starts, :limits
```

and try use `PARAM_STR` for `$search`;

```
$stmt->bindParam(":jobtitle",$search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: answer  updated  with a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the `DESC` keyword. If you want to sort it, just use `ORDER BY <column name> DESC` before the `limit` clause.

Try:

```
SELECT `jobtitle`, `company`, `location`, `employment`, `email`, `Description` FROM `featured job` WHERE jobtitle LIKE `:jobtitle` LIMIT :starts, :limits
```

Comment: What about ``:jobtitle``?